# Is it possible to autowire bean name in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

Is it possible to autowire bean name in Spring using annotations instead of using `BeanNameAware` interface?

Comment: You can use annotation @Component("beanName"). Or Are you solving another task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible out of the box, you can create own annotation `@BeanNameInjected` and register own [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate bean setter method with @Autowired.

```
public class SimpleMovieLister {

private MovieFinder movieFinder;

@Autowired
public void setMovieFinder(MovieFinder movieFinder) {
    this.movieFinder = movieFinder;
 }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: But `movieFinder` argument is not a bean name!

Comment: As someone mentioned in one of the post, you can perform any post processing related to bean in bean post processing. but in this case also you have to implement this interface or write if/ else inside post processing unit.

Comment: In some cases the harm of implementing interfaces is injection of new public methods that aren't related to business logic of the bean.

Comment: yes you are right, i think you can create a base class and implement all these extra interface in that class and provide method implementation in the base class. then also it will not resolve your issue :).